# Stage в JavaFX и многопоточность

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx

Предположим, у меня есть побочный поток в котором при определенных условиях должен выполняться метод primaryStage.show() Как это реализовать?

```
public class Main extends Application {
    private Stage stage;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        AnchorPane a1 = new AnchorPane();
        stage = primaryStage;
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(a1, 200, 200));
    }

    public class Run implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            stage.show();   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Приведите минимальный воспроизводимый кусок кода

Comment: public void start(Stage primaryStage){
//тут выполняется создания pane сцены и тд


}
//потом вложенный класс - побочный поток
public class SThread extends Runnable{
//тут мне надо вызвать метод  primaryStage.show()

}
считайте что мне нужно вызвать его из вложенного класса в параллельном потоке

Comment: Ну если воспроизводимный то
public class Class implements Application{
public static void main(String args[]){
launch(args);
}
public void start(Stage primaryStage){
AnchorPane a1 = new AnchorPane();
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(a1,200,200));
}
public class Run extends Runnable{
primaryStage.show();
}
}

Comment: этот вложенный класс является параллельным потоком еще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам надо обновить UI не из **JavaFX Application Thread** вы должны использовать `Platform.runLater()`.

Вариант с лямбдой

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    updateUi();
});
```

Вариант с `Runnable`

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateUi();
    }
});
```

Этот вызов можно делать в любом потоке.

Comment: аргументом должен быть объект реализующий интерфейс `Runnable`

Comment: я пока что не понимаю по какому принципу работает данный метод. Моя конечная цель при определенных условиях изменитьнесколько обьектов и обновить stage Как именно работает данный метод?

Comment: а почему не прочитаете в документации? проводите все изменения внутри метода `run` у объекта который вы передадите. я добавлю пример в ответ.

Comment: a что содержится в методе updateUi();

Comment: это просто метод для примера. вместо него должен быть ваш код.

Answer (score 0):

Я лично, чтобы изменять UI с потока JavaFx использую либо
        AnimationTimer или Platform.runLater
        но в основном AnimationTimer

```
    boolean update=false;
    AnimationTimer animationTimer=new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long now) {
            // от здесь уже процесс от JavaFx,  можешь спокойно обновлять UI
            if(update){
                update=false;
                // обычно у меня так выглядет
                // TODO обновление UI
            }
        }
    };
    animationTimer.start();
```

runLater почему-то я пока нигде ни использовал, но пробывал

```
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //  здесь уже поток от JavaFx
        }
    });
```

есть еще пару способов связанный с чем-то типа Task, но его не опробовал, из за усложненности